# Is there a possible memory leak in this AS3 code?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks, flash

Can you please point out if there's a possible memory leak in this AS3 code? A user of this program is saying that there seems to be a memory leak. 
function startCountdownToTargetDateTime is called after the program started and loaded user prefs XML file. The program is swf and is loaded into PowerPoint. The user said he ran it for the whole night and it reached 1.8 GB of RAM and crashed PowerPoint.

[image]

Comment: Not enough code. And *please* next time post actual letters, not a screenshot.

Comment: Using `new` makes unique **new** entries in memory. Declare `var msDiff : Number = 0` outside of any function and simply re-use that one variable in your functions (eg: use as `msDiff = targetDateTime...etc - currentDatetime...etc`). Also in your **tickToTargetDateTime** function do you need a new date everytime? Since running every 1000 ms why can't it be just add extra 1000 to the time's Number? Example `currentDatetime += 1000;` then followed by `msDiff = targetDateTime - currentDatetime`. If **targetDateTime** never changes you wouldn't need a new `.getTime` for it each & every 1 second.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause a memory leak. I would say that either the memory leak exists somewhere else in your code, or there's some problem with how the SWF is running in PowerPoint. Have you been able to reproduce the issue? Does it happen if you run the SWF in a browser or standalone player?

Comment: @Vesper Thanks for pointing out, noted.

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for your suggestions, noted. I set a new date every time because the timer is paused when PPT quit slideshow, and when PPT enters slideshow again, it produces incorrect times.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your suggestions, noted. I haven't been able to reproduce the issue. I did a test on the timer for 8 hours and had no problem. I asked the user to do a test on his PPT slideshow without the timer.